# How to handle HTML Arrays with App Engine Python?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I'm stuck with this problem I made an HTML Array, but I can't read it out with Python. Is it even possible to do it in App Engine? I read it was possible in PHP.

This is the html code:

```
<label for="hashtags">Hashtags: </label><br/>
{% for hashtag in stream.hashtags %}
    <input type="text" value="{{hashtag}}" name="hashtags[]" id="hashtags" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
{% endfor %}
```

This is how I'm currently trying to read the HTML Array:

```
newHashTags = self.request.get('hashtags[]')
for newHashTag in newHashTags:
    stream.hashtags.append(newHashTag)
```

This is in the post variable when I'm debugging.

```
MultiDict: MultiDict([('streamid', '84'), ('name', 'Akteurs'), ('description', '#stream'), ('hashtags[]', '#andretest'), ('hashtags[]', '#saab')])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to include the `[]` at the end of the name of a field you'd like to treat as a list or array, that's some PHP-specific magic.  Instead, just name the field `hashtags` and in your request handler do this to get a list of hashtags from the request:

```
newHashTags = self.request.get('hashtags', allow_multiple=True)
```

The `allow_multiple=True` argument will make `get` method return a list of all `hashtags` values in the request.  See [the relevant documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestdata.html) for more info.

You could also avoid the `for` loop by doing something like this:

```
newHashTags = self.request.get('hashtags', allow_multiple=True)
stream.hashtags.extend(newHashTags)
```